# Call php from C# for windows 7 mobile

Tags: c#, php, xaml, windows-phone-7

I have am a beginner in C#, php and the whole coding on mobile win 7. I have a problem with my code and there isnt any more forums/websites that i could search for the answer so i am posting the query here.

I am working on a windows 7 mobile project and in my code i need to call a php script from C# and later use the values that the php returns. The code is something like:

```
string url = "../test.php";
req = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(url);
IAsyncResult res = (IASync)req.BeginGetResponse(WebComplete, req);

private void Webcomplete(IAsyncResult a)
{
  var req = (HttpWebRequest)a.AsyncState;
  var res = req.EndGetResponse(a);
  ........
  ........
}
```

The code runs but nothing happens. When i put a breakpoint at BeginGetResponse i find it does not call WebComplete at all. Would you know why this is happening and what is the workaround? Also how can i assign the value i get from the php code to a variable, so that i could further manipulate the data.
Note: The url returns the correct values when i tested it from the browser.

Thanks for the help - Racheal

Comment: Does this have to be executed as asynchronous or can you change the code to by synchronous?

Comment: Good question! Honestly, i am not sure so i think i will go for Asynchronous.The above worked at some point for me but for a different php.

Comment: Your URL is relative, so that indicates (to me anyway) that you're running the PHP on the phone itself?  Is that correct (and if so how)?

Comment: My PHP codes are stored in a server and I am assuming that it is running in the server itself and not on the phone.

Comment: In Windows Phone projects, you can *only* invoke web calls asynchronously.

Comment: Thanks Dennis, but i have a question. If i were to call multiple PHPs to the database, one after another, then wont asynchronous web calls mess up my data. Is there another way to handle this.

Answer (score 0):

Two things to do.

First, fix the url to the php file.  As @ctacke mentioned the one you have points to the local device... which isn't hosting the php file unless you have some really weird stuff going on.

The second one is optional.  Instead of doing an asynchronous request, make it synchronous.  For example:

```
String postLocation = "http://myserver.com/test.php";

HttpWebRequest httpRequest = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(postLocation);
// Setting the useragent seems to resolve certain issues that *may* crop up with certain servers.  
httpRequest.UserAgent = "Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; MSIE 6.0; Windows NT 5.1; SV1; .NET CLR 1.1.4322; .NET CLR 2.0.50727)";

using (HttpWebResponse httpResponse = (HttpWebResponse)httpRequest.GetResponse()) {
    StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(httpResponse.GetResponseStream());
    string results = reader.ReadToEnd();
    // at this point you have the entire response in the results variable.  
    // Do with it as you please...
}
```

At the very least, if there is a real problem the synchronous method should give you immediate feedback on the issue.

Comment: Thanks for the reply but i am unable to add GetResponse() to the code. The only option i get is BeginGetResponse().

Comment: @Racheal:  Interesting.  Apparently GetResponse isn't supported on the mobile platform.  See this link for a better example: http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/windowsphone7series/thread/558880c6-cc9e-44cd-92e2-01e84e7c2333

Comment: @Racheal:  Ignore the synchronous part for now and just fix your url.